# Make the browser display whole DOM elements in a fallback font if they contain one or more special characters

Tags: javascript, css

We use the Titillium Web font for our web site. Some texts are written in languages that require non-ASCII-characters. This can result in some letters being displayed in Titillium web, some in a fallback font. I would like to achieve a more uniform typeface.

Is there a (smart) way to make the browser detect if a DOM elements contains one or more non-ASCII-characters, so that I could set a backup font for the whole element?

Comment: When you [set your web-font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), you can specify a list of fallback fonts the browser will try before it asks the OS which one to use. Show a bit of your code so we can help better.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question. We are using fallback fonts already. What I don't want is the browser to use several fonts to display the characters within one DOM element.

Comment: ... so let's say you have the information, what are you going to do with it? If you have a font that can handle both character sets, why not use just that?

Comment: Well, if I know a good solution, I'll implement it... Using another font is just what I want, but only for DOM elements containing characters that are not in Titillium Web. I can't use something like Arial for the whole website because we have a corporate design, and for aesthetic reasons.